# What is the meaning of "C4649: attributes are ignored in this context"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, alignment, c++14, compiler-warnings

What does this warning mean?

Here is the mcve.

```
template<class K> class TTT{
    public: alignas(alignof(K)) 
    union{ 
        char raw[sizeof(K)];        
        K rawK;
    }; //<-- error at this line
};
```

If I compile this single file with `ctrl+F7` in Visual Studio 2015, I will get this warning.

```
warning C4649: attributes are ignored in this context
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'TTT<K>' being compiled
```

I appear in my computer, but http://rextester.com can't reproduce this warning though.

**Other information :-**

- Notice that `TTT<K>` is never really instantiated.
- If I removed the word  `alignas(alignof(K))`, the warning will disappear.
- With some test case, this class is practically usable.

I can't really find any sites that has some useful description about it.

Has anyone ever encountered it before?

Comment: In VS2017, I get *error C2024: 'alignas' attribute applies to variables, data members and tag types only* which is probably what your (presujmably older) VS version should have said, if it had better support for `alignas`/`alignof`.

Comment: @Rook has the answer. I suggest you post it so it could be accepted.

Comment: @Rook  Thank! Yes, Rook has the answer!

Comment: In fact, "some programmer dude" had the answer, so I'm glad I didn't rush to post! A quick look at the [cppreference docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) shows that it is fine to apply to `union`s, and gives an example of usage with structs, etc.

Comment: @Rook - But the warning text you quoted says *"and tag types"*. Which is what a struct/class/union is. Not hard to surmise it was applied improperly, somehow :)

Comment: Yep, but by the time I'd checked that, an answer had already been posted. I generally like to err on the side of caution ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading e.g. [this `alignas` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) it should be placed between the `struct` or `union` keyword and the structure/union tag.

So it should be something like

```
template<class K> struct TTT{
    union alignas(alignof(K)) {
    //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //    Note placement
        char raw[sizeof(K)];        
        K rawK;
    };
};
```